# Absolute positioning without content wrapping

Tags: css, position, word-wrap

I'm experiencing a nasty css problem I can't seem to solve.
I want to position a wrapper inside a container with the `left` property (in the positive direction; negative seems to work for some reason) without the content inside to start wrapping up.
Here is a **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zp8Yb/3/)** for the following HTML and CSS.

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="one"></div>
        <div id="two"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
#container {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;

    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #000;

    /*white-space: nowrap;*//*Works for chrome, but not for firefox*/
}

#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    /*left: 100px;*/
}

#one, #two {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #000;

    margin: 10px;
    float: left;
}
```

If you uncomment the `left: 100px;`, you'll notice the two boxes get moved **but also** wrapped. In chrome, this can be fixed using `white-space: nowrap;` on the container. It doesn't work for Firefox, though, and also affects the text content.  I have tried removing `position: relative;` from the container and calculating the right offset with Javascript but that's somewhat inconvenient.

**Edit:** It does work with CSS3's `transform: translateX(100px)` but I'd still prefer the `left` variant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying a width for the wrapper seems to work in both Firefox and Chrome (and doesn't require the `white-space` property at all).  The CSS for `wrapper` becomes:

```css
#wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a bunch! It's always the little things it seems.